# How to remove extensions from urls in the website

Tags: web-deployment, phpdesigner

I try to remove extensions from the url by creating a .htaccess page in the root folderwith  the following code
RewriteEngine 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
but it is not working pls help me out......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

use this code in your .htaccess file
and remove the extensions of your php files in a href itself